# add staitc value to starting of an array which is formed by fetching results from MySQL

Tags: php, arrays

How do I add a static value as first element or starting of my array?  The data for array is coming from my database.

Below I am trying to add "Select Style" in the front but not it is just combing my first to elements.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM ImageInfo";

$db = new connection();

$result = $db->query($query);


while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $content[] = $info;
}
$result=array();

$count = count($content);

$result[0][] = "Select Style";

for ($x=0;$x<$count;++$x)
{
    $result[$x][] = $content[$x]['name'];
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Denoteone, Following should do the trick,

```
$result[0][] = "Select Style";
for ($x=0;$x<$count;++$x)
{
    $result[][] = $content[$x]['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue seems to be with the following lines

> $result[0][] = "Select Style";

and

> $result[$x][] = $content[$x]['name'];

You are setting the first value in the array as "Select Style" then in the first iteration of the for loop you have $x == 0 so it is overriding the value you put in

You can change

```
    $result[$x][] = $content[$x]['name'];
```

to

```
    $result[][] = $content[$x]['name'];
```

Alternatively you can remove the following line:

```
    $result[0][] = "Select Style";
```

And place the following directly after your for loop:

```
    array_unshift($result, "Select Style");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

> array_unshift

can solve the problem

```
<?php
  $queue = array("orange", "banana");
  array_unshift($queue, "apple", "raspberry");
  print_r($queue);
?>
```

after this code, the $queue array becomes

```
Array
(
  [0] => apple
  [1] => raspberry
  [2] => orange
  [3] => banana
)
```

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$result=array();
```

to this

```
$result=array( 'Select Style' );
```

And, btw, your code could use a little revamp

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM ImageInfo";
$db = new connection();
$result = $db->query($query);
$content = array('Select Style');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $content[] = $row['name'];
}
echo json_encode($content);
```